# Alignment of buttons in toggle button group in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular-material

I am trying to make a material tool bar with few material button inside. I want to align first button on left side and rest three buttons on right side of tool bar. I am trying to achieve this from CSS but no able to.

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup">
        <mat-button-toggle value="left" aria-label="Text align left">
          <mat-icon>format_align_left</mat-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="center" aria-label="Text align center">
          <mat-icon>format_align_center</mat-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="right" aria-label="Text align right">
          <mat-icon>format_align_right</mat-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
        <mat-button-toggle value="justify" aria-label="Text align justify">
          <mat-icon>format_align_justify</mat-icon>
        </mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
</mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>

<div class="example-selected-value">Selected value: {{group.value}}</div>
```

Comment: mat-button-toggle-group will group all the buttons together. So, they will remain in group. However, if you want them to be aligned on left side and right side then they should be removed from group. Try keeping buttons without mat-button-toggle-group and then keep styling for buttons

Comment: @Maruthi, yes that's what i tried but that gave me another issue while switching from toggle group to mat button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust some flexbox styling to make it work. The current implementation uses `display: inline-flex;`, while it needs `display: flex;`. Next to that, the second toggle (`.mat-button-toggle:nth-child(2)`) needs to be pushed to the right side. That can be achieved with `margin-left: auto`.

SCSS code

```css
.mat-button-toggle-group.mat-button-toggle-group {
  display: flex;

  .mat-button-toggle:nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: auto;
  }
}
```

Compiled CSS code

```css
.mat-button-toggle-group.mat-button-toggle-group {
  display: flex;
}
.mat-button-toggle-group.mat-button-toggle-group .mat-button-toggle:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Outcome
[image: Display mat-toggle different]

See [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqldpk?file=src%2Fstyles.scss) for an example. Note that the default toggle group needs to be overridden by adding the same class again in CSS and making it thus more specific.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. This is working on Stackblitz but when i am putting in my code , throwing error,          } expectedcss(css-rcurlyexpected)

Comment: @usersam I edited the answer with the compiled CSS code. Please add that to your CSS file.

Comment: I removed all the css and put only your css but it is still not aligning as per need.